# Audioplayer play on condition

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

i hv few images , and i am showing these images  through for loop, so i am getting a value in mCurrentImageView , which indicates which image is currently shown up.

now i want to play audio on each image view, different audios.
for ex,

```
if(mCurrentImageView ==0) {
play "a"
}
if (mCurrentImageView ==1)
{
play "b"
}
....
```

something like dat.
bu t i am not sure how to do this, since i should have one Audioplayer, which should play different audios  on the basis opf mCurrentImageView's value.

this is my Avaudioplayer code

```
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b"ofType:@"mp3"];
    fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

plz suggest, what should i do to move further.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVAudioPlayer` only allows you to specify an URL when it is initialized, thus, as eviltrue says, you have to create a new one to play a different file. E.g. assuming you have a property holding the paths and a property for the player:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSArray *paths;
@property (readwrite, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

And you have initialized the paths:

```
paths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
```

You can do the following when the image changes:

```
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:mCurrentImage];
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"mp3"];
fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
self.player = newPlayer;
[newPlayer release];
[self.player prepareToPlay];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: dats f9....but track should match to the image which is currenlty on view.so as i asked in my question, if(image ==1){play track1}...something like dat.

Comment: @shishir: Yes, thats what the array is used for - take a look at the `[paths objectAtIndex:mCurrentImage]` expression.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple solution is to use AVAudioPlayer. So when you want to play new sound you just release old player and create a new one with file you want to play.

Comment: i edit my question by adding my player code.So if i hv 20 audios, than i hv to create 20 AudioPLayer???is it like dat??

Comment: not really, you should just destroy and create a new player each time you need it.